# VBA Excel Align Pictures Horizontally in Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, vba, image, alignment

From some sample VBA code I attempted to modify,
I am aiming to learn Excel using VBA and hoping for guidance to align Pictures horizontally such as  5 pictures in one row then below a new row begins and repeat. For now I am using a hard value of 5, just to have it occur once though the results aren't what I expected. Here are two steps of the problem

1. Seems to take the first image then make a new row right away
2. Then vertically aligns two images on different new rows

I considered needing an additional counter to keep track of so the Macro will know when to introduce a new row.

```
Sub pictureCode()
'Automatically space and align shapes

Dim shp As Shape
Dim counter As Long
Dim dTop As Double
Dim dLeft As Double
Dim dHeight As Double
Const dSPACE As Double = 50

  'Set variables
  counter = 1

  ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll

  'Loop through selected shapes
  For Each shp In Selection.ShapeRange
    With shp
      'If not first shape then move it below previous shape and align left.
      
      If counter = 5 Then          
        .Top = dTop
        .Left = dLeft + dWidth + dSPACE
      Else
        .Top = dTop + dHeight + dSPACE
        .Left = dLeft
      End If

      'Store properties of shape for use in moving next shape in the collection.
      dTop = .Top
      dLeft = .Left
      dHeight = .Height
    End With

    'Add to shape counter
    counter = counter + 1

  Next shp

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be good to take Cells as reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please, It aligns shapes using the row reference (`Top` and `Left`):

```
Sub testAlignShapes()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, s As Shape, i As Long, colAlign As Long, startRow As Long
 Dim dWidth As Double, dSpace As Double, rngAlign As Range, iRows As Long, nrShLine As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 colAlign = 9 'column number to align the shapes
 startRow = 2 ' starting row
 nrShLine = 3 'how many shapes on the same row
 iRows = 3 ' after how many rows will start the following shapes row
 
 For Each s In sh.Shapes
    Set rngAlign = sh.cells(startRow, colAlign)
    i = i + 1
    If i <= nrShLine Then
       s.top = rngAlign.top: s.left = rngAlign.left + dWidth + dSpace
       dWidth = dWidth + s.width: dSpace = dSpace + 10
       If i = 3 Then i = 0: dWidth = 0: dSpace = 0: startRow = startRow + iRows
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the helpful comments in-code as well!   I will play around with the sample you provided me !

Comment: @Brandon Falk: Glad I could help! It should do what (I understood that) you need...

Answer (score 0):

thanks fane duru!

i modified the script if it was arranged vertically through trial and error.

```
Sub testAlignShapes()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, s As Shape, i As Long, colAlign As Long, startRow As Long
 Dim dWidth As Double, dSpace As Double, rngAlign As Range, iRows As Long, nrShLine As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 colAlign = 1 'column number to align the shapes
 startRow = 1 ' starting row
 nrShLine = 1 'how many shapes on the same row
 iRows = 42 ' after how many rows will start the following shapes row
 
 For Each s In sh.Shapes
    Set rngAlign = sh.Cells(startRow, colAlign)
    i = i + 1
    If i <= nrShLine Then
       s.Top = rngAlign.Top: s.Left = rngAlign.Left + dWidth + dSpace
       dWidth = dWidth + s.Width: dSpace = dSpace + 10
       If i = 1 Then i = 0: dWidth = 0: dSpace = 0: startRow = startRow + iRows
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```

*** iRows depends on how many rows the image covered then the next image will follow.

Thanks a lot sir FaneDuru